# Is EXT4 outdated for production?

Tags: linux, webserver, ext4, xfs, btrfs

I just downloaded OpenSuse 13.2, and now, it gives two different file system option than the `ext4` , but i see people debating about problems `btrfs` and `xfs`

So, if `ext4` is outdated, then which one is the best for production? (to serve static files from a webserver)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[btrfs is not stable](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Is_btrfs_stable.3F).  Do not use it in production.

This leaves you with a choice between XFS and ext4.  ext4 is a reasonably mature, modern filesystem, while XFS is older but still quite reliable.  XFS is good for extreme situations, when you have a lot of I/O, large files, large filesystems, etc.  If you do not have such needs, XFS may be overkill.

Comment: then if the application is simple with less users, then `ext4` will be far enough!